# How do I pull change records from ServiceNow for a specific system?

Tags: python, bash, ansible, servicenow

I'm trying to automate patching and need to find a way to pull change records from ServiceNow for specific servers and find out if a change window is open for that server.

I tried doing this in Ansible but so far I've had no luck. I'm wondering if there is a better way to do this? Maybe through Python or just something simple with using curl and bash? I've heard of some people having luck with rest APIs but I know very little about it.

Here is an example of my playbook using the snow_record module:

```
 - hosts: localhost
  connection: local
  gather_facts: no
  ignore_errors: True
  tasks:
  - name: Grab a user record
    snow_record:
      username: testuser
      password: somepass
      instance: myinstance
      state: present
      number: CHG9999
      table: change_request
      lookup_field: cmdb_ci.name=someservername
```

Error output:

```
  The full traceback is:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/root/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1553017980.16-56687342300902/AnsiballZ_snow_record.py", line 113, in <module>
        _ansiballz_main()
      File "/root/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1553017980.16-56687342300902/AnsiballZ_snow_record.py", line 105, in _ansiballz_main
        invoke_module(zipped_mod, temp_path, ANSIBALLZ_PARAMS)
      File "/root/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1553017980.16-56687342300902/AnsiballZ_snow_record.py", line 48, in invoke_module
        imp.load_module('__main__', mod, module, MOD_DESC)
      File "/tmp/ansible_snow_record_payload_0p5jn8/__main__.py", line 332, in <module>
      File "/tmp/ansible_snow_record_payload_0p5jn8/__main__.py", line 328, in main
      File "/tmp/ansible_snow_record_payload_0p5jn8/__main__.py", line 317, in run_module
    AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'UnexpectedResponse'

    fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {
        "changed": false, 
        "module_stderr": "Traceback (most recent call last):\n  File \"/root/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1553017980.16-56687342300902/AnsiballZ_snow_record.py\", line 113, in <module>\n    _ansiballz_main()\n  File \"/root/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1553017980.16-56687342300902/AnsiballZ_snow_record.py\", line 105, in _ansiballz_main\n    invoke_module(zipped_mod, temp_path, ANSIBALLZ_PARAMS)\n  File \"/root/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1553017980.16-56687342300902/AnsiballZ_snow_record.py\", line 48, in invoke_module\n    imp.load_module('__main__', mod, module, MOD_DESC)\n  File \"/tmp/ansible_snow_record_payload_0p5jn8/__main__.py\", line 332, in <module>\n  File \"/tmp/ansible_snow_record_payload_0p5jn8/__main__.py\", line 328, in main\n  File \"/tmp/ansible_snow_record_payload_0p5jn8/__main__.py\", line 317, in run_module\nAttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'UnexpectedResponse'\n", 
        "module_stdout": "", 
        "msg": "MODULE FAILURE\nSee stdout/stderr for the exact error", 
        "rc": 1
```

I tried snow_record_find. A module I found [here](https://github.com/garbled1/ansible_modules).

Playbook:

```
- hosts: mytest
  tasks:
  - name: Grab a user record
    snow_record_find:
      username: testuser
      password: somepass
      instance: someinstance
      #state: present
      #number: null??
      table: change_request
      query:
        AND:
          equals:
            active: "True"
            type: "standard"
            u_change_stage: "80"
          contains:
            u_template: "MY-Template"
```

Error output from that:

```
fatal: []: FAILED! => {
    "changed": false, 
    "module_stderr": "Shared connection to  closed.\r\n", 
    "module_stdout": "Traceback (most recent call last):\r\n  File \"/root/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1553019300.21-10858374496170/AnsiballZ_snow_record_find.py\", line 113, in <module>\r\n    _ansiballz_main()\r\n  File \"/root/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1553019300.21-10858374496170/AnsiballZ_snow_record_find.py\", line 105, in _ansiballz_main\r\n    invoke_module(zipped_mod, temp_path, ANSIBALLZ_PARAMS)\r\n  File \"/root/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1553019300.21-10858374496170/AnsiballZ_snow_record_find.py\", line 48, in invoke_module\r\n    imp.load_module('__main__', mod, module, MOD_DESC)\r\n  File \"/tmp/ansible_snow_record_find_payload_j9P62r/__main__.py\", line 260, in <module>\r\n  File \"/tmp/ansible_snow_record_find_payload_j9P62r/__main__.py\", line 257, in main\r\n  File \"/tmp/ansible_snow_record_find_payload_j9P62r/__main__.py\", line 249, in run_module\r\n  File \"/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pysnow/legacy_request.py\", line 91, in _all_inner\r\n    yield self._get_content(response)\r\n  File \"/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pysnow/legacy_request.py\", line 332, in _get_content\r\n    server_error['summary'], server_error['details']\r\npysnow.legacy_exceptions.UnexpectedResponse: Unexpected HTTP GET response code. Expected 200, got 401\r\n", 
    "msg": "MODULE FAILURE\nSee stdout/stderr for the exact error",
```

Comment: The 401 implies your credentials are wrong; perhaps try increasing the verbosity of ansible and see if emits more helpful information? `ansible-playbook -vvvv`

Comment: You may also want to try [this pysnow example](https://pysnow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/full_examples/fetch.html#first-record) and see if it's even possible for the library to interact with your instance, since that ansible module is just a wrapper around the `pysnow` library

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, what you're attempting is not easy. There is not an existing API in ServiceNow that will return the next available maintenance window for a given Configuration Item (CI / Server).

You could reverse engineer the [Maintenance schedule](https://docs.servicenow.com/bundle/madrid-it-service-management/page/product/change-management/task/t_CreateBlkoutMaintSched.html) functionality and create your own Scripted API on the ServiceNow platform to complete, but that is likely not worth the effort.

Just FYI, you can use the [REST API Explorer](https://docs.servicenow.com/bundle/madrid-application-development/page/integrate/inbound-rest/reference/r_RESTAPIExplorerElements.html) in ServiceNow to get code snippets for various languages, Python included.

And finally, there's some good [REST Web Service tutorials](https://developer.servicenow.com/app.do#!/trainlist/app_store_learnv2_rest_madrid_rest_integrations?v=madrid) available as a part of ServiceNow's Developer program, through which you're also able to get a free dedicated ServiceNow instance to play with.